# MySQL: Set session var to NULL on SQLException

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sqlexception

I have a before insert trigger on table 'a', which essentially duplicates and translates the query for insertion into table 'b'. Here's an pseudocode example of this trigger:

```
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF @inserting IS NULL THEN
    SET @inserting = 1;
    INSERT INTO b SET
      col1 = NEW.col1
      col2 = NEW.cola
      col3 = some_stored_proc(NEW.col3);
    SET @inserting = NULL;
  END IF
END
```

However, as you might notice, `@inserting` will be left as 1 if the INSERT fails. I need to ensure that it is set back to NULL should the insert to table 'b' fail, while causing the original insert on table 'a' to fail as well (so as to not have mismatched data between the two).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: As an aside to prevent confusion, the reason for this trigger is actually to allow for a new schema while maintaining a legacy schema which some legacy apps rely on.

Comment: is a cgi script an option?

Comment: @marabutt: Honestly, I don't know, but considering I have no experience with writing CGI scripts, I'm more inclined to say no and explore possibilities with the slightly more familiar triggers before I look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I discovered that [DECLARE...HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-handler.html) and [RESIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resignal.html) will solve this issue.

```
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    SET @inserting = NULL;
    RESIGNAL;
  END;
  IF @inserting IS NULL THEN
    SET @inserting = 1;
    INSERT INTO b SET
      col1 = NEW.col1
      col2 = NEW.cola
      col3 = some_stored_proc(NEW.col3);
    SET @inserting = NULL;
  END IF;
END
```

`DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION` allows you to perform statements on an SQL exception (and exit the current procedure when finished).

`RESIGNAL` will pass the error on.

Comment: but what I don't understand, is that if there's an exception while inserting in `b`, it would simply exit the trigger and @inserting would be reset anyway. Your process would no loop over after an exception (AFAIK).

Comment: @Sebas `@inserting` is set to 1, the `INSERT INTO b` fails, and `SET @inserting = NULL` never runs because of the exception. @inserting is left as 1 for the rest of the session.

Comment: I'm curious: what are you doing with this session variable?

Comment: @Sebas preventing an opposing trigger on table b that performs the inverse action from firing as a result of this trigger.

Comment: I see. Then your solution is fine I guess. Maybe you could just use "INSERT IGNORE INTO b..." instead, but then you wouldn't see the exception. Up to you.

Comment: @Sebas `INSERT IGNORE` would actually be the opposite of what we want here–It would cause the insert to silently fail and the original query that triggered this to go through, which would cause data inconsistency. We want to resignal the exception, so that either both queries work, or neither query works (sort of a makeshift transaction), which will help prevent inconsistencies.